# Login System Help - "Getting 4 errors"

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication, system

I get these errors, when I try to use the system.

> Use of undefined constant session_id - assumed 'session_id' in C:\wamp\www\UCP\header.inc.php on line 16
>
> mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\UCP\header.inc.php on line 21
>
> mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\UCP\header.inc.php on line 22
>
> : Use of undefined constant IsLoggedIn - assumed 'IsLoggedIn' in C:\wamp\www\UCP\Dashboard.php on line 3

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("connection.php");

$user = IsLoggedIn();

if($user)
{
    $expires = time() + (60 * 15);
    mysql_query("UPDATE 'active_users' SET 'expires' = " . $expires . " WHERE 'user' = " . (int) $user . "");
    
}

function IsLoggedIn()
{
    $sessID = mysql_real_escape_string(session_id);
    $hash = mysql_real_escape_string(hash("sha512", $sessID.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
    
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT 'user' FROM 'active_users' WHERE 'session_id' = '" . $sessID . "' AND 'hash' = '" . $hash . "' AND 'expires' > " . time() . "");
     
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($query))
    {
        return $data['user'];
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling mistake in your SQL query.

Change `SLECT` to `SELECT` in the `IsLoggedIn()` function and always use (`) to pack table or field name.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.Use of undefined constant session_id: define your session_id
2. For mysql error just change SLECT with SELECT
3. Use of undefined constant IsLoggedIn : pull your IsLoggedIn function in the top of the page.
```

Comment: function can be placed anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Basically, consider write it in PDO or mysqli, at least, because mysql_query is depreciated. But in this case:

```
 1) $sessID = session_id();
 2) the mistake is here --->  WHERE session_id = '$sessID' AND hash= '$hash' AND expires > " . time(). "");     First, you INSERT Hash and SESSION_id TO DB and then you SELECT it.
 3) $num=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($num !==0 ) { 
    }
4) mysql_query("UPDATE active_users SET expires = '$expires' WHERE user='$user'");
5) if($user !==null)
6) if you still receiving errors, check if row & table names are correctly written.
```

Comment: Yeah just this one Use of undefined constant IsLoggedIn - assumed 'IsLoggedIn'

Comment: Would this be correct? <?php
$servername = "localhost"; 
$database = "ucp";    
$username = "root";        
$password = "";          

$connect = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
    mysql_select_db($database, $connect) or die(mysql_error());

?>

Comment: mistake is in 2) delete the WHERE clause to check it and then reconsider the clause

Comment: check if you have columns: user,session_id,hash,expires correctly written. Then check if expires has an INTEGER type. Also try: $data = mysql_fetch_array($query); instead of assoc

Answer (score 0):

in your query change `SLECT` with `SELECT`

Comment: I'm just gwtting this error, now Use of undefined constant IsLoggedIn - assumed 'IsLoggedIn'